# Forward mail with Postfix and update Reply-To: and rewrite sender

Tags: postfix-mta

I try to rewrite the sender address with a new domain and also add the original sender address to the Reply-To: header.

Postfix 3.5.18 is active.

The update of the sender domain is working with **sender_canonical_maps**

If I understand the documentation the **smtp_header_checks** should be used to update the Reply-To in the header.

It looks like this is the solution but I need to use original sender address instead of no-reply@example.com
`^From:(.*)$/   REPLACE From: no-reply@example.com`

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I've had the pleasure to work with a Linux engineer at a company I work for working on somewhat the same needed use case. The Linux engineer came up with this:

Have this in the /etc/postfix/main.cf:

```
sender_canonical_classes = envelope_sender
smtp_header_checks = regexp:/etc/postfix/header_checks
```

Then have this in the /etc/postfix/header_checks:

```
/Message-ID:.*\%(.*)/ PREPEND Reply-To: $1
```

Do a:

```
Postfix reload
```

To load this new configuration.

Test with:

```
mail -r emailyouwantinreplyto@domain.bla -s "test with reply-to" emailyouwanttosenditto@domain.bla
```

Hope this works for you too.